# Why does KeyCollection keys = dict.Keys; give compile-time error?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Suppose, I have a Dictionary as follows:

```
class MyType
{
     //... ...
}

Dictionary<string, MyType> dict;
```

Then,

```
KeyCollection keys = dict.Keys;
```

shows compile-time error.

Why is that?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. The answer is trivially found by actually writing the code and observing the `Keys` and `Values` properties. Or by reading the documentation.

Comment: @Flater, this is not homework. I am confused.

Comment: The second example you edited in does not throw a compile time error.

Comment: Was this a rubber duck moment? You've asked some very well received questions on StackOverflow and have been asking C# questions for over 10 years, how have you come across this only now? No offence intended, just curious.

Comment: @ColinM, Coz, I am out of software development for the last, say, 10 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Dictionary class (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs). You will see

```
public KeyCollection Keys { get; } // This gives you collection of string
public ValueCollection Values { get; } // This gives you collection of MyType
```

UPDATED:
To show you how to get it

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MyType> dict = new Dictionary<string, MyType>();
        Dictionary<string, MyType>.KeyCollection myKeys = dict.Keys;
    }
```

Comment: `KeyCollection keys = dict.Keys;` shows compiletime error.

Comment: You need to put Dictionary<string, MyType>.KeyCollection keys = ..... I updated the answer to show you the type. Although, you just need to do var keys = .....

Comment: @user366312, you want the shortest type? Then you just need to use "var keys =....".

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = dict.Keys;
IEnumerable<MyType> values = dict.Values;
```

Comment: Keys returns an object of type KeyCollection and Values returns a ValueCollection. Not arrays. You would need to call `.ToArray()` to get arrays

Comment: There should always be a description for you code how it work in the OP case? It help for the future readers also.